# Django 3 doesn't load css file

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am testing my django project locally.

[image: The templates and static files are as listed:]

My settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'firstapp',
]

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Hello/static"),
]
```

Urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from firstapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

When I run the server, the html file is loaded but Google Chrome indicate that:

[image: Google Chrome]

**django not displaying image**
I cannot understand why?

Comment: That is a strange url on your screenshot (and please tend not to post textual information as screenshots; HTML, URLs and error messages are text). Your template files are not supposed to be accessible directly via browser and you should not attempt to access them like that. Open your root `/` URL and `views.index` should render your template in response. And revoke access to project folder from whatever websever you're serving it with. By the way, how do you start/run/instantiate your Django project?

Comment: You have to use `manage.py runserver` instead of PyCharm's show in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the url you probably used your IDE's "show in browser" option. By doing this you're not actually rendering a template - you're just displaying the raw html file (thats why we can see the `{% load static %}`. What you have to do even to see how your html looks like is to make a `view` and `render` the template as a `return` of the view. Assign a view to some url and access it with that url - then `{% load static %}` will actually do it's magic work.